# MS SQL, outer column in sub-query

Tags: sql-server, subquery, cross-apply

giving this table definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE Attivita_T041(Kint_TP013_IdAttivita INT)

CREATE TABLE TP004_LinkPersonaArea
    (int_T013_IdArea int, 
     dte_T013_DataInizio date, 
     dte_T013_DataFine date, 
     int_T013_IdPersona int, 
     int_T013_IdRuoloArea int)
go


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Q_TP013_Pianificazione] (
    [Kint_TP013_IdAttivita]      INT     ,
    [Ksin_TP013_IdArea]          SMALLINT,
    [Ksin_TP013_AnnoRifPian]     SMALLINT,
    [sin_TP013_Giorni]           SMALLINT   
);
```

i need a table function with a query that join Attivita_T041 table with many others and now i have to add a subquery to get two information: total of `[sin_TP013_Giorni]` and total of  `[sin_TP013_Giorni]`  for `[Ksin_TP013_IdArea]` where current user actualy work in (reading from `TP004_LinkPersonaArea`)

that is this part of the query:

```
SELECT ....
FROM Attivita_T041
INNER JOIN   ---- many other tables here
LEFT OUTER JOIN PersonaArea_T013
        ON int_T013_IdPersona = @idUtente 
        AND dte_T013_DataInizio <= @dataRiferimento
        AND (dte_T013_DataFine  > @dataRiferimento OR dte_T013_DataFine IS NULL)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                Kint_TP013_IdAttivita
            ,   SUM(sin_TP013_Giorni)           AS GiorniPianificatiAnno
            ,   SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN Ksin_TP013_IdArea = int_T013_IdArea THEN sin_TP013_Giorni
                    ELSE 0
                END)                            AS GiorniPianificatiAnnoArea
            FROM 
                    Q_TP013_Pianificazione
                INNER JOIN dbo.FN_DettaglioPianificazione(YEAR(@dataRiferimento), 0)
                    ON Progressivo = Ktyi_TP013_ProgressivoPian
            WHERE
                    Ksin_TP013_AnnoRifPian = YEAR(@dataRiferimento)
            GROUP BY Kint_TP013_IdAttivita
        ) AS Pianificazione
        ON Kint_TP013_IdAttivita = Kint_T041_IdAttivita
```

but i can't do that because `int_T013_IdArea` column i nedd is outer of subquery

searching on SO i find the suggestion to use `OUTER APPLY` so i switch to this:

```
OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1
                SUM(sin_TP013_Giorni)           AS GiorniPianificatiAnno
            ,   SUM(CASE 
                    WHEN Ksin_TP013_IdArea = int_T013_IdArea THEN sin_TP013_Giorni
                    ELSE 0
                END)                            AS GiorniPianificatiAnnoArea
            FROM 
                    Q_TP013_Pianificazione
                INNER JOIN dbo.FN_DettaglioPianificazione(YEAR(@dataRiferimento), 0)
                    ON Progressivo = Ktyi_TP013_ProgressivoPian
            WHERE
                    Ksin_TP013_AnnoRifPian = YEAR(@dataRiferimento)
                AND Kint_TP013_IdAttivita = Kint_T041_IdAttivita
        ) AS Pianificazione
```

but now i get this error:

> Multiple columns are specified in an aggregated expression containing
>   an outer reference. If an expression being aggregated contains an
>   outer reference, then that outer reference must be the only column
>   referenced in the expression.

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you need to do the SUM in a sub query? Otherwise also try and look towards using SUM as a window function.

Comment: before subquery i try the sum in direct select but can't do it: if i move sub query tables as stanadard joined tables i get a cartesian product: i need two of this kind, one is in the example, i omitted the second for brevity. i only need to say if this way is possible or if i am forced to do a subquery for every sum